# How to send POST request in ajax with json?

Tags: javascript, android, ajax, cordova, post

I am developing Android phonegap application with jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js and cordova 5.
i am calling $ajax for servlet.

PS: It is working fine in GET request. but using GET how to send lengthy json request?

```js
   $.ajax({
  url:localStorage.getItem("URL")+"/BackgroundTracking",
  type:"POST",
  data:{waypoints:JSON.stringify(jsonArray)},
  dataType:'json',
  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  crossDomain:true,
  cache:false,
  success: function(data)
   {
   if(data)
    {
      
     db.transaction(function(tx)
     {
         
    for(var k=0;k<submittedRecordsIds.length;k++)
   {
     tx.executeSql('DELETE FROM watchPoints_tb where id=?',[submittedRecordsIds[k]]);
    console.log("records deleted");
         
   }
     });   
     }
      else
       {
      console.log("in else after response");
       }
        
 },
     error: function (result) 
      {
              
    alert('Request Status: ' + result.status + ' Status Text: ' + result.statusText + ' ' + result.responseText);
       }
   });
```

Using POST i am getting the following error:

`$.ajax POST returning “status”:403,“statusText”:“Forbidden” cordova android`

Comment: Is this an API you control? Is it an API to which you need to authenticate?

Comment: @kerri I want to send this request to my API where I need to submit this json data into db.